# Substitute ' with \' in double-quoted string

Tags: ruby, regex

The task is simple - I have a string like `"I don't know"` and I want substitute `'` with `\'` (I know that I don't have to escape single quotes). How can I do it?

Comment: Similar [Escape doube and single backslashes in a string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774808/escape-doube-and-single-backslashes-in-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: @chown: nah, this problem is about how gsub interprets the special match variables with an escape prefix in the replacement string.

Comment: @maerics Yea, probably not a duplicate, but *similar*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the block form, it should work in all versions of Ruby:

```
s.gsub(/'/) {"\\'"}
# => "I don\\'t know"
```

**[Edit]**

The reason is that the [`gsub` method](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_string.html#String.gsub) has special handling for backslash sequences in the replacement string which correspond to the special match variables.  So you can use `$'` (and `$1`, etc.) directly in the substituted string by using the form `\\'` (and `\\1`, etc.) instead.

The block form of gsub doesn't have this behavior, so that's the workaround when you're trying to sub in a string that looks like a special backslash sequence.

Comment: Also `s.gsub(/'/,'\\\\\'')` or `s.gsub(/'/, "\\\\'")`. But @maerics is clearer.

Comment: I guess it somehow matches `$'` value when you do `s.gsub(/'/,"\\'")` right?

Comment: @Bohdan: right, in the replacement string you can use some of the special match variables (e.g. `$'`, `$1`) by using the escaped form (`\\'`, `\\1`) but the block form of gsub doesn't have this "convenience" =)